# How to add buttons to wkWebView?

Tags: swift3, ios8, xcode10

Because we make `wkWebView` as the root view, the button I added on my layout doesn't appear on screen. Then I tried to add `wkWebView` as a subview of the root view, but the app crashes. Then I found about `UIBarButtonItem`, but it seems that you could only create 2 buttons.

I need to add 5 buttons anywhere on the screen. Is there a workaround for this? I'm a newbie on ios development and I'm not that good at using the interface builder.

After trying @Matic Oblak's code and placing it on `loadView()` where I do my `wkwebview` initialization, I'm getting an error saying "Warning: Attempt to present SomeViewController on WebViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

This is my current code.

```
override func loadView() {
//        let contentController: WKUserContentController = WKUserContentController()
//        let config: WKWebViewConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
//
//        contentController.add(self, name: "callbackHandler")
//        config.userContentController = contentController
//
//        webView = WKWebView(
//            frame: UIScreen.main.bounds,
//            configuration: config
//        )

       //webView.navigationDelegate = self
       //webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       //webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false

       //view = webView

       if let webViewContainer = webviewContainer {

           // Initialize:
           let contentController: WKUserContentController = WKUserContentController()
           let config: WKWebViewConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()

           contentController.add(self, name: "callbackHandler")
           config.userContentController = contentController

           let webView = WKWebView(frame: webViewContainer.bounds, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration()) // Create a new web view
           webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false // This needs to be called due to manually adding constraints

           webView.navigationDelegate = self
           webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
           webView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false

           // Add as a subview:
           webViewContainer.addSubview(webView)

           // Add constraints to be the same as webViewContainer
           webViewContainer.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: webViewContainer, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
           webViewContainer.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: webViewContainer, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
           webViewContainer.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: webViewContainer, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
           webViewContainer.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: webViewContainer, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))

           // Assign web view for reference
           self.webView = webView
       }
   }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    if(someVar1.isEmpty && someVar2.isEmpty){
           showSomeDialog()
       }
}
```

The first commented lines on `loadView()` are my previous code for reference.

After placing @Matic Oblak's code on `viewDidLoad()`, I'm getting a black screen. Also, after placing the code that calls `SomeViewController` on `viewDidAppear()`, the error is gone but I'm still getting the black screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `WKWebView` has a bit of a nasty bug that it crashes when added in storyboard. But you can do that in code. What I usually do is create a view in storyboard just as a web view panel (usually full screen but not if you have some tool bars) then just add a new web view as a subview. I still use constraints to add the web view:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class WebViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet private var webViewContainer: UIView? // A view on which a web view will be added to
    private var webView: WKWebView? // Web view manually added

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let webViewContainer = webViewContainer {

            // Initialize:
            let webView = WKWebView(frame: webViewContainer.bounds, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration()) // Create a new web view
            webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false // This needs to be called due to manually adding constraints

            // Add as a subview:
            webViewContainer.addSubview(webView)

            // Add constraints to be the same as webViewContainer
            webViewContainer.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: webViewContainer, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
            webViewContainer.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: webViewContainer, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
            webViewContainer.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: webViewContainer, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
            webViewContainer.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: webView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: webViewContainer, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))

            // Assign web view for reference
            self.webView = webView
        }
    }

}
```

So here `webViewContainer` is dragged from storyboard as any view you want. It can even be the main view of the view controller if you want to.

The rest should be explained in the comments.

So using this procedure you don't need to "hack" adding subviews on top of everything. You can add your button normally in your storyboard.

**Note:** The problem with using webViewContainer as main view is that web view will be added later than the rest of views so it may cover those you added in storyboard. You need to either send the web view to back or bring overlaying items to front. It is just adding `webViewContainer.sendSubviewToBack(webView)` but I still prefer to use a separate view just for web view.

Comment: @rminaj Try it I guess? I would rather leave it in `viewDidLoad` and possibly move whatever you have in `loadView` to `viewDidLoad`. I assume you are misusing `loadView`.

Comment: look at my code. can you tell how can I misuse `loadView()`? I still don't really get how things work on iOS.

Comment: @rminaj I would put that into `viewDidLoad`. Also I see you are missing a call to `super` in your `loadView`. And `showSomeDialog` should most likely be called in `viewDidAppear`. I guess just avoid `loadView`. It is probably very similar in your case to `viewDidLoad` but still you want to ensure that view is in fact loaded before you start using it. This does not mean it is shown on the screen, this method gets called right after the view is instantiated and will be shown on the screen after it.

Comment: which method are you referring to that "gets called right after the view is instantiated"? I've been using `loadView()` because that's what the tutorial I followed before is using.

Comment: @rminaj The method `viewDidLoad` is called right after the view is instantiated. It is just before it is being shown on the screen so just before user sees it. Before the animation when using animations even. So it is perfect to do any additional setup and is present in a template if you create a new view controller class.

Comment: After applying everything you've said, it's finally working. Thank you very, very much. my iPad is just having problems with it's wifi connection so I can't test it properly. I'll just ask again if I have more questions

Answer (score 1):

You could add floating button on top of your viewcontroller by using some third party library. Let's say using [Floaty](https://github.com/kciter/Floaty) or with any other similar.

Comment: That looks promising

Comment: Do you know something like that for iOS 8 and below?