# Add button to WKWebView

Tags: swift, wkwebview

I am trying to add buttons to WKWebView but I could not find a way for it.
I load the Instagram website with below code but could not add button before user images for all items in main page.

```
let url = URL(string: "https://www.instagram.com")!
webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
```

Is there a any way to add photo before all posts user image?

This is the one of the examples: https://ibb.co/n38fX3R

Comment: please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52866816/how-to-add-buttons-to-wkwebview